# Is there a way to copy data into postgresql from CSV while skipping the values that are already in the table?

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql

I want to create a database in postgreSQL, my source file is a CSV that keeps updated everyday, I want to update the the process of ingesting this data into my table in postgres.

I have been using

```
\COPY school_records FROM '/home/nickson/daily_report.csv' DELIMITER ',';
```

Since I want this action to be done everyday after midnight, I need to find a away to make the process to only copy new records in the CSV and not copy everything.

Is this something possible? if yes how if no what are the suggestions do you have.

Comment: I'd use `\COPY` to a temp table and then `INSERT` needed records from there to the final destination.

Comment: I agree with @JamesBrown that you should use a staging table.  Since it is a daily process there is no need to create a temporary table each time.  You can truncate the staging table, load it, then do an `insert`.  If records might be updated, then use `on conflict`, if records are only added, then `insert` from a `select. . . except` query.  You could also look into FILE_FDW.

Comment: I also agree to the comments above. In addition, you might have a look at the __*merge*__ statement in postgresql that lets you perform something similar to an 'upsert'. You can specify what should be done in the _insert_ case and in the _update_ case individually, also with the option to 'do nothing' in the update case. I assume that you have a unique index on the target table, otherwise the merge will not work properly.

Comment: There is no ```MERGE``` in Postgres. There is ```ON CONFLICT``` on ```INSERT```.